# rails zeus custom_plan for server port modification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeus

I want to use `zeus s -p 12345` in my project.
Of course I could use shell alias to make this like

```
alias zsp='zeus s -p 12345'
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to directly modify the custom plan to make this?
So next time only need to type `zeus s` than it automatically use the port in the `custom_plan` or `zeus.json` file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a custom port with a 'custom_plan.rb' like this:

```
require 'zeus/rails'

module CustomPort
  def options
    super.merge Port: 12345
  end
end

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails
  def development_environment
    require 'rails/commands/server'
    ::Rails::Server.include CustomPort
    super
  end
end

Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

I know this is ugly but this was the only way I could get this to work. I think overriding `default_options` would be better but it doesn't work.